# Map values in array to their sorted index

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to minimize the values in an array by mapping them to their sorted index.

For example  `[8, 8, 15, 3, 5]` would become `[2, 2, 3, 0, 1]`. I was able to accomplish with the following code but it takes a long time for large arrays.

```
a = [8, 8, 15, 3, 5]
a_mapped = np.zeros(len(a))
a_sorted = sorted(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
     a_mapped[i] = a_sorted.index(a[i])
```

Is there a faster way to do this, possibly using a numpy function?

Comment: By its very nature, `list.index()` is a slow operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `scipy`, you can use `rankdata` from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
import numpy as np

a = np.array([8, 8, 15, 3, 5])

rankdata(a, method='dense') - 1
# [2 2 3 0 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.unique` may give what you want:

```
In [29]: arr=np.array([8, 8, 15, 3, 5])
In [30]: np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
Out[30]: (array([ 3,  5,  8, 15]), array([2, 2, 3, 0, 1]))
```

Comment: Great solution!